# Assigning DATENAME to VARCHAR2

Tags: plsql, variable-assignment

Im am new to Pl/SQL and i haven't found a way to assign the `DATENAME(weekday, pd_date)` to `ps_weekdayname`, in this case an error is raised when assigning:

```
--Get day of week
  FUNCTION f_dayofweek(pd_date DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    ps_weekdayname VARCHAR2;
  BEGIN
    ps_weekdayname = DATENAME(weekday, pd_date)
    RETURN ps_weekdayname;
  END;
```

Is there another way to assign the variable?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DATENAME](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/datename.php) is SQL Server function, and it does not exist in PL/SQL. 
To achieve the same result using PL/SQL, you need to do something like this:

```
to_char(pd_date, 'DAY')
```

Your function would be something like this:

```
--Get day of week
  FUNCTION f_dayofweek(pd_date DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    ps_weekdayname VARCHAR2;
  BEGIN
    ps_weekdayname := to_char(pd_date, 'DAY');
    RETURN ps_weekdayname;
  END;
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i searched for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your comments. I updated my answer accordingly.